Why does Pandas to_csv method behave unexpectedly sometimes?
I am using Pandas to_csv method to save my Dataframe to CSV file. Index of the Dataframe is in Datetime format. The format used in index is %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f (2024-07-08 10:53:07.20).
Most of the time to_csv saves Dataframe without any wrong index value but sometimes last index value gets stored in the format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S instead of %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f. It skips the milliseconds part. This happens only with the last index.
What could be the reason behind this, and what can I do in order to stop it from happening?
I tired of looking inside the code of the to_csv method. But I think it is written in C, which I don't much understand.

It might be that you don't have milliseconds, you should force the format you want as string

I would check original dataframe. In my experience some data may use a different format (string?), which makes some weird results. Try to force to a date, and check if you have NaT

Pandas will trim the datetime display to the required precision to be as short as necessary to be unambiguous (%Y-%m-%d if there is no sub-day precision, or %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S if no sub-second precision, else %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f).
Let's assume this example:
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(4)},
                  index=pd.date_range('2024-01-01 01:23:45.678', periods=4))

CSV output:
,col
2024-01-01 01:23:45.678,0
2024-01-02 01:23:45.678,1
2024-01-03 01:23:45.678,2
2024-01-04 01:23:45.678,3

If you have a lower precision, then the milliseconds are removed automatically (but the seconds are kept):
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(4)},
                  index=pd.date_range('2024-01-01 01:23', periods=4))

The CSV output will be:
,col
2024-01-01 01:23:00,0
2024-01-02 01:23:00,1
2024-01-03 01:23:00,2
2024-01-04 01:23:00,3

You can force the date format in to_csv with date_format='...':
df.to_csv('your_file.csv', date_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

Or convert the index to string with strftime:
df.set_axis(df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')).to_csv()

CSV output:
,col
2024-01-01 01:23:00.000000,0
2024-01-02 01:23:00.000000,1
2024-01-03 01:23:00.000000,2
2024-01-04 01:23:00.000000,3


So forcing the date_format will solve my problem. I'll try and let you know if it does.
